# Check in TFS solution file which is checked out by another user

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I am working on the TFS solution as multiple developers are working on the same project. One file is checked out by another teammate and the virtual machine on which he was working has been deleted. Now I want to edit the file which is checked out by that user but the VS showing me error that the file is checked out by another user. Is there any way to check in that file?

Answer (score 1):

Use [TFS Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/) to delete his Workspace using the Workspace sidekick. When you delete the work space, any check-outs are undone on the server. You could also use [tf.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms245474(v=vs.90).aspx) to delete the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

From your machine, Get the latest version of that deleted file.

Place that file on virtual directory where it was deleted.

Checkin the file and then you are good to go